# Create new variables in a loop (PHP)?

Tags: php, variables

I have a problem with PHP. I'd like to create a new variable each time, my loop runs through. For example: If my loop runs for the first time, it should create a new variable called $loop1, if it runs the second time $loop2 with a different value, third loop - $loop3...
Here is a reference of my code, any help is appreciated!

```
while ($x < count($lines)) {
    $info
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Why not create an array and add values to that?

Comment: I had the same idea, but I'd like to go further on with the variables.

Comment: Use a data structure to store the values and then assign those values to their respective variable.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this?  It is not the normal way to create a set of related values, which is to use an array, vector, list, map (which are all bundled together as "array" in PHP)

Comment: Your next question will be: "How can I use $loopN variables when I don't know how many I got?". So yes, read up on arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create variables dynamically using braces in PHP, e.g.:

```
${"loop" . $x} = "some value";
```

(Reference: [PHP "variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php))

But note that this might be a bad idea in real-world application. 
It might be more appropriate to use an array or a map instead, e.g.

```
$loopVars = []; // create a new array
while (...) {
    $loopVars[] = "some value"; // add a new array element
}
```

Comment: As a note dynamic variables are usually a **super bad idea** and should be avoided whenever possible. They can create astonishingly damaging security holes.

Comment: @tadman I agree to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are searching for something like an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$data = array();

while ($x < count($lines))
{
    $data[] = ... whatever you want to store
}
```